# Dynamic array of Integer type in processing

Tags: java, arrays, processing

How can I create a Dynamic array that holds Integer values (not int) in PROCESSING.

I have stored the String into a text file (String Str= "12,13,14,15"). Now i need to split and convert them to Integer type after loading the text file.

Comment: Do you mean `new Integer[n]` or `ArrayList<Integer>`?

Comment: Okay, you've said what you need to do - but you haven't said how you've tried to achieve it. What have you tried, and what went wrong? Have you got as far as splitting the numbers? Trying to parse each part in turn?

Comment: I meant new Integer[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String str = "12,13,14,15";
String[] strArray = str.split(",");

int[] intArray = new int[strArray.length];

for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
    try {
        intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // Handle the exception properly as noted by Jon
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that just printing the stack trace is almost *always* the wrong way of handling exceptions. It's what IDEs tend to suggest automatically, but the code should pretty much never be left that way.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed but this should be handled by the designer how to handle it. I left it there so OP can handle it depending on the spec/design.

Comment: But without mentioning it (or indeed writing *any* explanatory text) you're basically inviting the OP to copy and paste your code without change. IMO you should have *at least* added a TODO comment... and ideally written some text in your answer as well as the code. (Code-only answers are almost always less useful than those with an explanation.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Done but didn't know that what you find in the net is good for direct "copy paste" in your project.

Comment: No, it's *not* a good idea - but that doesn't mean it doesn't happen :(

Comment: @JonSkeet well that sucks.

Comment: I was able to convert the Strings into the int format using the spilt function. But the code needed was to suit the code in  one.add("Triangle",new Integer[]{157,274,157,266,157,259,157,253,157,247,157,241,157,235};one.bind("ka","detected"); Its at the place of 157,274,157,... ,235 where i should be able to use the values that i have loaded.

Comment: @MELWIN one.add("Triangle", intArray);

Comment: @SajalDutta thank you very much. Your idea helped me to solve my task... thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since code is reading a file, I would use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) instead:

```
    String str = "2,3,4,5,6,7";
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(/*yourFile*/));
    //Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
    while(sc.hasNext()) {
        sc.useDelimiter(",");
        intList.add(sc.nextInt());
    }

    Integer[] wrapperArray = new Integer[intList.size()];
    intList.toArray(wrapperArray);
```

Scanner: [How-to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-to-use-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Comment: there is no keyword Scanner in processing 2 :(

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code.. It works fine for me

```
        try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("data.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String str = br.readLine();

        String strArray[] = str.split(",");
        Integer intArray[] = new Integer[strArray.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
            intArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[i]);
            System.out.println(intArray[i]);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
       // TODO: handle exception
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I hope this will help you.