# I don't know how to use a function of the Scanner class

Tags: java

so I have to do a Flask Machine assignment and I have a small problem with the scanner class. I created a method in which I want to add the bottle types(A B or C) to an arraylist. So I don't really know how many bottles I will enter. The thing is I want my scanning to stop once I encounter a ,,0". I know I have to use a while loop but using it like this doesn't work because by the time I want to add the bottle to the list, it jumps to the next scanned bottle.

```
 While(input.next()!="0"){
  list.add(input.next());
  count++;
```

}

Comment: use equals() for string comparison

Comment: Yeah I know that, but that wasn't my problem/question.

Comment: Please.. everyone on earth, stop using `==` for comparing Strings. I beg you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the result of the `input.next()` callback in a variable and terminate the loop if it's equal to `0`. For example:

```
while (true) {
   String next = input.next();
   if ("0".equals(next)) break;
   else {
      list.add(next);
      count++;
   }
}
```

More info about:

- [How to compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)
- [How to use the Scanner class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-to-use-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You call `next()` twice. Store the first value.

```
String next;
while (!(next = input.next()).equals("0"))
{
    list.add(next);
    count++;
}
```