# This code gives me an incompatible types error. It says it requires a Scanner but found String. I don't understnd how I can fix it

Tags: java

```
public static void getBooks(){

    int bookNum = 0;
    bookFile = new File(args[0]);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(bookFile);

    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
        bookNum += 1;
        input = input.nextLine();
    }
    ...
}
```

I need it to add the number of books as long as there are books to add meaning while there is a next line.

Comment: What is the declared type of the variable `input`? What is the return type of the method `nextLine()`?

Comment: `input.nextLine()` returns a String, and you're trying to put it into `input`, which is a Scanner. Change that.

Comment: Try looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-to-use-the-scanner-class-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    input = input.nextLine();
```

The two `input`s are probably meant to be two separate variables. Change this to something like:

```
    String line = input.nextLine();
    // use `line' here
```

Answer (score 0):

This `input = input.nextLine();` makes no sense. What do you want to do? Just run `input.nextLine()`