# Assigning array variable inside of a loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

new to programming but trying to assign to my double variable inside my for loop.
Basically I need to use Math.abs and Math.sin, which is sort of throwing me off. Any help is appreciated. If i need to provide any more information please let me know.

```
double[] xValues = new double[arrayAmount];
double[] yValues = new double[arrayAmount];

xValues[0] = minimumValue;

for (int index = 0; index==arrayAmount; index++)
{

    yValues = 20.0 * Math.abs((Math.sin(xValues))); // java saying this is wrong

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

```
for (int index = 0; index==arrayAmount; index++)
{
   yValues[index] = 20.0 * Math.abs((Math.sin(xValues[index])));
}
```

Notice that you are getting a value from a specific index of xValues and saving at a specific index of yValues.

Also notice that your xValues only have 1 element. So if you code specify more about the values or the problem, we could be able to help you more.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in Java used to access to an element on an specific index of an array is:

```
nameOfArray[index]
```

so if you want to assign some value to `yValues` in an specific index, you have to use:

```
yValues[index] = 20.0 * Math.abs((Math.sin(xValues[index])));
```

**Note** that your loop won't work unless the length of the array is `0`. Try changing the loop condition to:

```
for (int index = 0; index < arrayAmount; index++) { ... }
```

or

```
for (int index = 0; index < yValues.length; index++) { ... }
```

Comment: thank you! this really helped. I have one more quick question if you could help. I need to add to the xValue a user-inputted number every time the loop goes around. Can you help with how to code that? Would it be"""" xValues[index] = xValues[index] + increment;  """"

Comment: You can use a `Scanner`: Declare the scanner object outside the loop: `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);` Then inside the loop: `xValues[index] = sc.nextDouble();`. You can also see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-to-use-the-scanner-class-in-java) for further information.

Comment: Before the loop the user already declared the increment value. The value never changes, i just need the xValue to increase by this increment every go-around. Example would be xValue[0] = 5 ... increment = .25 ... xValue[1] = 5.25 ... xValue[2] = 5.50  ... etc. Sorry if i wasn't being clear enough.

Comment: Then what you did (`xValues[index] = xValues[index] + increment;`) would work. This can also be simplified by `xValues[index] += increment;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an index to get/set specific values in an array.

If you have:

```
double[] xValues = ...;
```

And you want to refer to the `double` at index, say, 3:

```
xValues[3] = ...;
... = xValues[3];
```

You need to add `[index]` to your arrays.

Also, by the way, your condition is wrong in your `for` loop. The loop will go *until* the condition is true, not *while* the condition is true. You have:

```
for (int index = 0; index==arrayAmount; index++)
```

This says "loop while index==arrayAmount". You want:

```
for (int index = 0; index<arrayAmount; index++)
```

Answer (score 0):

array is like rack on the shelf each have value block so instead of

```
yValues = 20.0 * Math.abs((Math.sin(xValues)));
```

put the value in each rack by yourself like this:

```
yValues[index] = 20.0 * Math.abs((Math.sin(xValues[index])));
```

now java does not says this is wrong

Comment: Don't forget `Math.sin(xValues[index])`.