# Using scanner to read numbers with multiple line breaks

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

How can I read the input (numbers) using the `java.util.Scanner` class when the numbers are separated by any number of line breaks?

An example might be like the following:

```
23333 
.
.
.

332332

.
.
.
3333
```

Comment: why won't you try googling it first? there already are zyllions of questions (and answers) about it. possible duplicate of [How to use the Scanner class in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-to-use-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Comment: @GuruMan94 where do you want to read you data from ? A file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set multiline [delimeter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.lang.String%29). Assuming you read your numbers from a file :

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    scanner.useDelimiter("[\r\n]+"); // for unix "\n" and windows "\r\n" endings

    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("read number = " + x);
    }

    scanner.close();
```