# How to fix a word requesting program?

Tags: java

I created a JAVA code, and I don't have any errors, but when I run the code, the output does this:
Enter a word: Thank you for entering a word! And it does not let me enter anything, when I intend for the code to let me enter a word, then it checks if it is a word, and gives the answer if it is a word, or none if it isn't. (It is my first time asking on this site) Here's the code:

```
package files;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Testprinter {

static boolean myBoolean = false;   
static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);


public static void main(String[] args){
    String usersInput;

    while(myBoolean != true)
    {   
    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");

    usersInput = userInput.toString();
    myBoolean = checkInput(usersInput);
    }

    checkifComplete();

}

public static boolean checkInput(String usersInput){
    if(usersInput == (String)usersInput)
    {
        return true;

    } else { return false; }

}
public static void checkifComplete(){
    if(myBoolean = true){
        System.out.print("Thank you for entering a word!");

    }

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is using `userinput.toString()`, when you should be using `usersInput = userInput.next();`.  You are currently retrieving the string representation of the scanner, not getting a word.

Corrected main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String usersInput;

    while(myBoolean != true)
    {   
    System.out.print("Enter a word: ");

    usersInput = userInput.next();
    myBoolean = checkInput(usersInput);
    }

    checkifComplete();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is wrong:

```
if (usersInput == (String)usersInput)
```

It should be:

```
if (usersInput.equals(usersInput))
```

In Java, strings (and in general: all *objects*, that is all types that are non-primitive) *must* me compared using the `equals()` method, which tests for **equality**. The `==` operator is fine for testing equality between primitive types, but for objects it tests for **identity** - a different concept, and 99% of the time, not what you want.

And besides, you're comparing a string with itself! it'll always return `true`, I'm quite sure that's not what you want to do… notice that the parameter must have a different name, currently it's called just like the attribute. Perhaps this is what you meant?

```
public static boolean checkInput(String input) {
    return usersInput.equals(input);
}
```

Comment: You can use `==` to test - it just checks something other than what you might expect, right? That the objects are the same, rather than their contents are equal

Comment: Downvoter here.  This doesn't fix the code; the issue is that he is reading the toString result.  It is part of it, though.

Comment: I'm not downvoter,  but OP has different problem, using scanner

Comment: Ok, agreed. But given that the question is titled "How to fix a word requesting program?", my answer solves at least part of the problems

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `scanner.nextLine();` thats reason its not asking you enter anything.

Instead of  
 `usersInput = userInput.toString();`

Use:

```
  String  usersInputStr = scanner.nextLine();
```

Follow this link -  for how to use scanner: [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-could-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class)