# How to convert that c++ code in to java

Tags: java, c++, converters

This is the c++ code.

```
while(scanf("%d%d", &m, &n) != -1) {
     //some logic
}
```

how to convert this code into java?.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-could-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class, you have a similar problem

Comment: Take a look at the Scanner class

Answer (score 2):

```
While(console.readLine() != - 1) 
{
Some logic
}
```

Comment: in my c++ code n and m are two integer variables. But in your java code that variables are doesn't used.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
  Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    int m,n;
    while( (m =scanner.nextInt()) != -1 && (n=scanner.nextInt()) != -1) {
         //some logic
        System.out.println(m +"\t"+n);
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong. `nextInt` returns the scanned int, but `scanf` returns "the number of items of the argument list successfully filled" or EOF.

Comment: @zenith your are right.