# Is it possible to make the user input the width and height of any shape?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, user-input

I am trying to write a code the asks the user: Which shape you want to draw?

and based on the choice, the user enters the parameters of the shape and it appears on the screen.

example: if user choose Rectangle, then they have to key in the height and width.

Is that possible to do ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Yassin I just know how to add the values by myself, I just change the values from this code  "g.drawRect(200, 100, 100, 200);" but am wondering how to make the user enter the values.

Comment: Post what you've coded already. It makes it generally easier to answer and you do not break one of Stack Overflow's rule.

Comment: @ItssMohammed So use a `Scanner` or some other input method and store the entered values into variables, then use the variables as parameters instead of your own hard-coded numbers.

Comment: @ItssMohammed, `but am wondering how to make the user enter the values` -  Read the [Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). You could use JOptionPanes to prompt for the values. You could use a JDialog with text fields.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible.

This is how you use scanner:

[How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Intro to content in URL above:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String username = scanner.nextLine();
```

**EDIT:**

Here's a program that applies the concept above and takes radius from user and draws a circle on a frame:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Painting extends Frame{

 int num=0;

Painting(){
   super("Paint");
   setSize(300,300);
   setVisible(true);

   Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter Radius");
   num = myScanner.nextInt();

  repaint();
      }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawOval(50, 50, (2*num), (2*num));
     }

      public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          new Painting();
         }
        }
```

Comment: this doesn't relate to the question, if you want to answer a comment, answer by comment

Comment: @niceman, I appreciate the feedback. I edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, removed my downvote :)