# Java on Eclipse simple program

Tags: java

I'm new to java and we're using Eclipse in college.

I need to create a class (named Rectangle) that contains two variables:
double dblLargeur, dblHauteur (stands for height and width in french)

The class should also contain two methods:
public double getSurface() - returns the surface of the rectangle
and main() - to test the class

Can you show me the easiest way to code this program in java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Comment: Please be more specific with the question.

Answer (score 2):

Scanners work to help get user input.

To get a string,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String myStr = scan.nextLine();
```

Integers

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scan.nextInt();
```

Your class is just using a scanner.

```
public Class Rectangle{
    private double dblLargeur;

    private double dblHauteur;
    //create the variables

    public double getSurface(){
         return dblLargeur * dblHauteur;
    }
    //your method



    public static void Main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        dblLargeur = scan.nextDouble();
        dblHauteur = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(getSurface());

    }
}
```

Notice how we use the `nextDouble()` to set the width and height.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this -->

```
public class Rectangle {
    double height, width;
    public Rectangle(double height, double width){
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }
    double getSurface(){
        return height * width;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        // do practice here
    }
}
```