# Changing a hardcoded object

Tags: java, object

I have tried googling this, and looked for a while, but have not found anywhere that explains how to do this well

```
  SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee = 
     new SalariedEmployee("bob", "Smith", "222-22-2222", "800");
```

The variables are firstname, lastname, social security number, and weekly salary.

How would i change that to something where i can ask what each of the variables should be such as

```
  SalariedEmployee salariedEmployee = 
     new SalariedEmployee(firstName, lastName, ssn, salary);
```

and then ask

```
what is the employee's first name?
what is the employee's last name?
What is the employee's ssn?
What is the employee's salary?
```

If anyone can explain this, or has seen this explained somewhere else your input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Read inputs from a user using a Scanner object or a Buffered Reader and save them locally. Initialize the object after you have all the inputs. Alternatively you can have set methods and assign them in any order you like.