# Error in reading Input from DataInputStream in java

Tags: java

Firstly I have made a folder named juet and then I have made two packages inside that folder. First one is Student package which takes care of all the students in university

```
package juet.stud;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.DataInputStream;

public class Student {

    String name;
    public int roll_no;
    int std;
    char grade;

    public Student() {
        try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Enter name of student:");
            name = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Enter roll no.:");
            roll_no = in.readInt();
            System.out.println("Enter std:");
            std = in.readInt();
            System.out.println("Enter grade");
            grade = in.readChar();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void showInfo() {
        System.out.println("Name of student: " + name);
        System.out.println("Roll no.: " + roll_no);
        System.out.println("Std: " + std);
        System.out.println("Grade: " + grade);
    }
}
```

Another package which I have made is Staff which takes care of all staff in the university

```
package juet.staff;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.DataInputStream;

public class Staff {

    public int id;
    String name, specialization;
    char group;

    public Staff() {
        try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Enter id:");
            id = in.readInt();
            System.out.println("Enter name:");
            name = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Enter area of specialization:");
            specialization = in.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Enter group");
            group = in.readChar();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void showInfo() {
        System.out.println("ID: " + id);
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("Area of specialization: " + specialization);
        System.out.println("Group: " + group);
    }
}
```

And then at the last I have made `MyUniversity` Class in which I was using both the packages

```
package juet;

import juet.stud.Student;
import juet.staff.Staff;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Console;

class University {

    Student[] stu;
    Staff stf[];
    int studCount, staffCount;

    University() {
        try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Enter capacity for students:");
            int x = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            //stu = new Student[x];
            System.out.println("Enter capacity for staff:");
            x = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            stf = new Staff[x];
            studCount = staffCount = 0;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }

    void newStudent() {
        stu[studCount] = new Student();
        studCount++;
    }

    void studInfo(int roll
    ) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < studCount; i++) {
            if (stu[i].roll_no == roll) {
                stu[i].showInfo();
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No match found.");
    }

    void newStaff() {
        stf[staffCount] = new Staff();
        staffCount++;
    }

    void staffInfo(int id
    ) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < staffCount; i++) {
            if (stf[i].id == id) {
                stf[i].showInfo();
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No match found.");
    }
}

class MyUniversity {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        University juet = new University();
        int ch;
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("\tMAIN MENU\n");
            System.out.println("1. Add student\n2. Add staff member\n3. Display info about specific student\n4. Display info about specific staff member\n0. Exit\n\tEnter your choice");

            try {
                ch = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
                switch (ch) {
                    case 1:
                        juet.newStudent();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        juet.newStaff();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("Enter roll no. of student to display info:");
                        int roll = in.readInt();
                        juet.studInfo(roll);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("Enter ID of staff member to display info:");
                        int id = in.readInt();
                        juet.staffInfo(id);
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        return;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Incorrect choice.");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is arising when I am calling `University` object in the main class it is asking for two inputs

1).Enter capacity for students 
so I enter 3 
and again it ask for 
2)Enter capacity for staff

But when I enter the integer there it is running infinite times 
and showing error

> java.io.Exception:Stream closed
>
> at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.getBufIfopen(BufferedInputStream.java:170)
>
> atjuet.MyUniversity.main(MyUniversity.java:76)
>
> at java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(DataInputStream.java:513)

Please help me Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You are using the wrong class. `DataInputStream` and the methods `readUTF()` and `readInt()` can not be used for reading text from the console. It is designed to read binary content encoded by a different Java program using `DataOutputStream`.

The following question and answers show you how to do it right:
[How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Comment: System.in isn't the Console.

Comment: @Wojciech Kazior: Because you are using the deprected method `readLine()`

Comment: @Mgorgon: System.in is not the console but the question clearly indicates that the OP uses it as console.

Comment: @Wojciech Kazior You don't have to close Scanner. If you don't close it System.in will not be closed.

Comment: @ Wojciech Kazior: `close()` is not called automatically. Scanner does not have an `finalize` destructor at all: See [Scanner.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Scanner.java)

Comment: Thanks @ Wojciech Kazior: Your answer was correct thanks a lot