# How to properly read in a string in Java 7 with java.utils.scanner

Tags: java, java-7

I'm working through a tutorial on Java and am having trouble on a trivial task. I need to be able to read a string from `stdin` and then concatenate it with another string and print it to `stdout`. Here is the code I'm using:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 4;
        double d = 4.0;
        String s = "HackerRank ";

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        /* Declare second integer, double, and String variables. */
        int i2;
        double d2;
        String s2;
        /* Read and save an integer, double, and String to your variables.*/
        i2 = scan.nextInt();
        d2 = scan.nextDouble();
        s2 = scan.nextLine();
        /* Print the sum of both integer variables on a new line. */
        System.out.println(i2 + i);
        /* Print the sum of the double variables on a new line. */
        System.out.println(d2 + d);
        /* Concatenate and print the String variables on a new line; 
            the 's' variable above should be printed first. */
        System.out.println(s + s2);
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

According to [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java), I'm doing everything right, but the tutorial is showing `s2` is being assigned an empty string and Java is only printing "HackerRank ".

What am I missing in my understanding of `scan.nextLine()`?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks! That question helps a lot.