# Java -Jar "my project" not executing in C.P (windows)

Tags: java, netbeans, cmd

I am trying to run a java file in the command prompt. the project was made in NetBeans. so I tried running it with `java -jar "D:\Java Projects\Algo1\dist\Algo1.jar"` which is what NetBeans told me to run in the command prompt. however, I get the following: [image: my errors in cmd]

my code is:
`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner N = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        Scanner K = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));
        Scanner L = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)));

        System.out.println(K);
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? Your code seems to run, i.e. the output you get is what `System.out.println(K);` does.

Comment: @Thomas its my first time doing this sort of thing, but I was expecting a place for me to enter in the value for k

Comment: In that case you should reread the tutorials and documentation on `Scanner`. You need only one and then use that to query the user, e.g. by calling `next()`.

Comment: @Thomas thanks, ill do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `System.out.println(K)`, java will print the argument (`K`) to the console. In this case the output tells you that you have an instance of the class `java.util.Scanner` and its properties.

When you want to read an input from the console, you should use the `nextLine()` method from the `Scanner` class, for example

```
String input = K.nextLine();
```

You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11871792/7677308

Comment: Just the thing I was looking for. Works great