# How to read String using Scanner Class?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s=scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String: " + s);

    }
}
```

Input: Welcome to Java tutorials
output: Welcome to Java tutorials

Comment: I don't see the problem?

Comment: I bet there are already many awnsers to your question on G-O-O-G-L-E

Comment: You have asked an answer

Comment: when i am run this code i am getting output String:

Comment: try with String s= scan.next();

Comment: Yes you are printing `"String: " + s`, so it prints the string `String: ` + the input. If you only want the input, then just do `System.out.println(s);`.

Comment: I also tried with scan.next(); but it is given the output only String: Welcome

Comment: So what output do you want?

Comment: i want output : Welcome to Java tutorials

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Answer (score -3):

**Use this code**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter the String");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Output String = " + input);


    }
}
```