# How to take user input using StringBuffer in java?

Tags: java, string

I tried this code but its not working

```
import java.util.*;
class StringBuffer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StringBuffer Name1=new StringBuffer();
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        Name1.append(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println(Name1);
    }
}
```

If the StringBuffer is per-defined then its works. But it fails to take input from user.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `class StringBuffer` which is already a built-in class in Java. 
Ref: [Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)

When you instantiate an object like `StringBuffer Name1=new StringBuffer();` within your custom defined class `StringBuffer`, then it creates an object with reference to your custom defined class `StringBuffer`.

You need to create an object of Java's inbuilt `StringBuffer class`.

Change your class name to something else or use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) which is not thread safe but faster than StringBuffer.

Additionally, using `Scanner` class to read your input.
[How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Comment: I changed the class name to St but there is an error E:\>javac St.java St.java:9: error: cannot find symbol Name1.append(in.nextLine()); ^ symbol: method append(String) location: variable Name1 of type StringBuffer 1 error

Comment: Also do `St Name1=new St();`

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct but the class name is wrong. change your class name and run it.

Comment: I changed the class name to St but there is an error     E:\>javac St.java
St.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        Name1.append(in.nextLine());
             ^
  symbol:   method append(String)
  location: variable Name1 of type StringBuffer
1 error

Answer (score 0):

`StringBuffer` is a predefined class in `java.lang` package which you are trying to use but as the name of your class clashes with it, it uses your class definition instead of the predefined one.

Here `Name1.append(in.nextLine());` you are calling `append` method which is not implemented by your class hence will raise an error `cannot find symbol`.
Change your class name to something unique and you are good to go. Nothing wrong with the input.

Comment: I changed the class name to St but there is an error E:\>javac St.java St.java:9: error: cannot find symbol Name1.append(in.nextLine()); ^ symbol: method append(String) location: variable Name1 of type StringBuffer 1 error

Answer (score 0):

no need to change your class name wheather it's StringBuffer or not.
But do one change in your class. Surely it'll take input from user side

```
public class StringBuffer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.lang.StringBuffer Name1 = new java.lang.StringBuffer();
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        Name1.append(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println(Name1);
    }
}
```

It will solve your problem.

Comment: @Parthav if your problem has been solved. then accept the answer.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235