# How to get console input from user and add string to an array list?

Tags: java, input

The thing I need to know is how can I get input from the user through the console and add it to an array list to keep the data stored? May someone kindly walk me through the process of getting this done for me?

What I know how to do so far:

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner(Sytem.in);
system.out.println("Please type in task to add to your to do list.");
String[] todo = new String[] {

}
```

Comment: take it as good Homework . And DIY.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I know how to set up the scanner thing but not how to put the user input in a custom array list for it to store

Comment: Who's upvoting this?

Comment: Please show your effort on your work first before you seek for a help

Comment: edit your question and show us how you set up the scanner.

Comment: I just did please review it

Comment: Please, before asking a question check out if there are any same questions around otherwise you are going to get negative voting very often. If you are going to use the site in the future could you please read Q&A

Comment: I'm sorry this is my first time here, I'll make sure to do that.

Comment: All fine. Just remember, that this is a community with concrete rules of asking question. If you want to get a clear answer, you should ask clear and non-duplicate question. Again, to know more about rules read Q&A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use Scanner, using something along the lines of .next() etc. would be handiest. There's lots of information in the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

They provide some example code that should indicate how this works. It's always best to have a look at the docs and trying to run the example code they provide to get an understanding before posting on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

You may use command line arguments to pass some initial data [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html).

There is also so called a "streams" notion (not Stream API) [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html).

IMHO the simplest way to accomplish so using Scanner [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java).

There is also a blog of a very cool guy there you can find answers to most of your questions [link](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-the-standard-input-in-java/).