# Beginner here - java IF ELSE used with text

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I just started reading about JAVA and I want to make a little program that when using Scanner is I type "yes", "no" or just something random I will get different messages.The problem if with the lines:

```
 if (LEAVE == "yes") {
        System.out.println("ok, lets go");
     if (LEAVE == "no") {
        System.out.println("you dont have a choice");
} else {
        System.out.println("it's a yes or no question");
```

I receive the error : Operator "==" cannot be applied to "java.util.scanner", "java.lang.String". I saw on a site that it would be better if I replaced "==" with .equals,but I still get an error..

Help please :S

### Code below:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner LEAVE = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("do you want to answer this test?");
        LEAVE.next();

        System.out.println("first q: would you leave the hotel?");
        LEAVE.next();
        if (LEAVE == "yes") {
            System.out.println("ok, lets go");
        }
        LEAVE.nextLine();
        if (LEAVE == "no") {
            System.out.println("you dont have a choice");
            LEAVE.nextLine();
        } else {
            System.out.println("it's a yes or no question");

        }
    }}
```

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner LEAVE = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Implies that LEAVE is Scanner class object. Right.

```
if (LEAVE == "yes")
```

You are comparing the Scanner type object with String type object and hence you are getting

```
Operator "==" cannot be applied to "java.util.scanner", "java.lang.String"
```

Now consider

```
LEAVE.next();
```

you are calling next() which belongs to LEAVE object. That next function is suppose to read a value and return that to you. So what you do is receive this value in another `String` type object and then further compare it to 'YES' or 'NO' or whatever.

```
String response = LEAVE.next()
if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){
   // do something
}else if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){
   // do something else
}
```

More about `Scanner` class
[GeeksForGeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scanner-class-in-java/)