# how can i read a string here in java programme

Tags: java, stack-overflow

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        String s = scan.next();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();

        // Write your code here.

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

what is the problem in my code i'm new in java

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more specific - "what is the problem" and "I'm getting error" helps no one to answer. Error message and description of expected behaviour usually help.

Comment: For this specific question consider using `nextLine()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here:

```
String s = scan.next();
```

Introduce addtional line to skip newline:

```
String s = scan.next();
scan.nextLine(); /* add this */
```

**OR**

Replace that line with:

```
String s = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: guys i used the nextLine but it still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Since the question isn't clear, I'm guessing you have the problem with the string.

This will reads until there is a space.

```
String s = scan.next();
```

If you want to read a string after the space consider doing this:

```
String s = scan.nextLine();
```