# String concatenation with input string

Tags: java, string

```
    String s = "Vivek";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = scan.next();
    String sResult = s + s1;
    System.out.println(sResult);
```

I want to concatenate String S with input string s1 that is "ojha is a Software developer"

I'm not getting the correct output.

```
Expected Output:
Vivek ojha is a software developer.

Actual output:
Vivek ojha
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What is your question actually?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Your code looks fine.

Comment: you probably wanted to use scan.nextLine()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Do it as @Michal stated:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Vivek";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    // see next line: nextLine()
    String s1 = scan.nextLine();
    String sResult = s + s1;
    System.out.println(sResult);
}
```

Comment: What exactly does it do or not do? In my environment, this is working

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner.next()` reads a single token. Unless you have configured the Scanner otherwise, this means a string without any whitespace in it.

Either call `next()` multiple times to get all the number of tokens you want; or use `nextLine()` to read the entire line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Vivek";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = scan.nextLine();
    String sResult = s + " " + s1;
    System.out.println(sResult);
}
```

Expected Output :

**Vivek ojha is a Software developer**

Actual Output :

**Vivek ojha is a Software developer**

Comment: Good, Happy Coding.. :)

Comment: It is working good in my machine... try this updated main method

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringConcatenation {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1 = "Vivek";
        String s2 = sc.nextLine();
        String s3 = s1 + " " + s2;
        System.out.println(s3);
    }

}
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

String s = "Vivek";

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.nextLine();  \\to scan the nextline after the value of s
String s1 = scan.nextLine();  \\to scan inputted string
System.out.println(s + s1);
```

----This Code worked in HackerRank--------