# Getting run time input in Abstract class in Java

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

> **Problem Statement** is "To develop a Java Program to create an abstract class named `Shape` that contains two integers and an empty method named `printArea()`. Provide three classes named `Rectangle`, `Triangle` and `Circle` such that each one of the classes extends the class Shape. Each one of the classes contains only the method `printArea()` that prints the area of the given shape."

In this program, I want to get the two integer values contained by the abstract class `Shape`, from the user (run time) instead of compile time.

***This is my code***

```
abstract class Shape

{   

    abstract void Printarea();

    int a=10,b=2;;

}

class Rectangle extends Shape

{

    void Printarea()

    {       

       System.out.println("area of rectangle is "+(a*b));

    }

}     

class Triangle extends Shape

{

    void Printarea()

    {       

        System.out.println("area of triangle is "+(0.5*a*b));

    }

}   



class Circle extends Shape

{       

    void Printarea()

   {       

        System.out.println("area of circle is "+(3.14*a*a));

   }  

}   

class Main

{

    public static void main(String []args)       

    {     

       Shape=b;

       b=new Circle();      

       b.Printarea();

       b=new Rectangle();

       b.Printarea();    

       b=new Triangle();

       b.Printarea();

   }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Comment: Use Scanner - do read about it.

Comment: he dont want scanner. he want to initialize value a, b. i thought it

Comment: @sajib OP wants to get integer values from user at run time. Values are already initialized at abstract class.

Comment: @sajib I want to get the values from user at run time in the abstract class itself not in main method!

Comment: The problem statement mentioned that the abstract class should contain two integer values!

Comment: then what you want?

Comment: I want to read those values from the console! I know Scanner would help me to get those values from user.If I get the values of the integers via Scanner in the abstract class, how can I able to invoke them since we can't create object for abstract class! @sajib

Comment: that's i said. you want it

Comment: i give one way. you can do it in creation time

Comment: Part of being a good citizen here is upvoting good answers and selecting an answer that solved your problem. If one of these answers was helpful to you, please upvote and select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add Setter and getter method for variables a,b ;
here's my code

```
package com.docker.container.controllers;

 /**
 * @author atwa Jul 29, 2018
 */
public abstract class Shape {

abstract void Printarea();

int a = 10, b = 2;

/**
 * @return the a
 */
public int getA() {
    return a;
}

/**
 * @param a
 *            the a to set
 */
public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
}

/**
 * @return the b
 */
public int getB() {
    return b;
}

/**
 * @param b
 *            the b to set
 */
public void setB(int b) {
    this.b = b;
}

static public class Rectangle extends Shape {

    void Printarea()

    {

        System.out.println("area of rectangle is " + (a * b));

    }

}

static class Triangle extends Shape

{

    void Printarea()

    {

        System.out.println("area of triangle is " + (0.5 * a * b));

    }

}

static class Circle extends Shape

{

    void Printarea()

    {

        System.out.println("area of circle is " + (3.14 * a * a));

    }

}

// area of circle is 314.0
// area of rectangle is 20
// area of triangle is 10.0
public static void main(String[] args)

{

    Shape b = new Circle();
    b.setA(5);
    b.setB(5);

    b.Printarea();

    b = new Rectangle();

    b.Printarea();

    b = new Triangle();

    b.Printarea();

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shape b;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = in.nextInt();
    int y = in.nextInt();

    b = new Circle(x, y);

    b.Printarea();

    b = new Rectangle(x, y);

    b.Printarea();

    b = new Triangle(x, y);

    b.Printarea();

}

private static int Abs(int a) {
    return a < 0 ? -a : a;
}
}

abstract class Shape {

int a, b;

public Shape(int a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}

abstract void Printarea();

}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
 public Rectangle(int a, int b) {
    super(a, b);
}

void Printarea()

{

    System.out.println("area of rectangle is " + (a * b));

}

}

class Triangle extends Shape {
public Triangle(int a, int b) {
    super(a, b);
}

void Printarea()

{

    System.out.println("area of triangle is " + (0.5 * a * b));

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Scanner class 
like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some quick code but works as expected and would give you idea:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

abstract class Shape {

    int a = 10, b = 2;

    Shape(int a, int b){
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }

    abstract void Printarea();

}

class Rectangle extends Shape {

    Rectangle(int a, int b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

    void Printarea() {
        System.out.println("area of rectangle is " + (a * b));
    }

}

class Triangle extends Shape {

    Triangle(int a, int b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

    void Printarea(){
        System.out.println("area of triangle is " + (0.5 * a * b));
    }

}

class Circle extends Shape {

    Circle(int a, int b) {
        super(a, b);
    }

    void Printarea() {
        System.out.println("area of circle is " + (3.14 * a * a));
    }

}

class Z {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Shape shape=null;

        String input;
        int width, height;

        while (true) {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("which shape? circle/rectangle/triangle (write any other thing for quitting): ");
            input = scanner.nextLine();

            if(!"circle".equalsIgnoreCase(input) && !"rectangle".equalsIgnoreCase(input) && !"triangle".equalsIgnoreCase(input) ){
                System.exit(0);
            }

            System.out.println("height: ");
            height  = scanner.nextInt();

            System.out.println("width: ");
            width = scanner.nextInt();

            if("circle".equalsIgnoreCase(input)){
                shape=new Circle(width, height);
            }
            else if("rectangle".equalsIgnoreCase(input)){
                shape=new Rectangle(width, height);
            }
            else{ // == triangle
                shape=new Triangle(width, height);
            }

            shape.Printarea();

        }

    }

}
```