# Getting keyboard input in java

Tags: java

I am writing a text to speech application in java, but I want a situation whereby as the user strikes a key, the application speaks that key as he presses it, pls am stuck I need help.! I am using the jframe class(GUI drag and drop netbeans) scanner won't work. Its for console!!! I need to get individual characters pressed by the user in a container and pass it to the speech engine to speak from a JText area

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order to be able to help you, we need to have more information: what platform are you using and what have you tried so far.

Comment: Please post additional details such as code lines where is it failing, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys!! Well I HV thought of the scanner class but after creating an object of the scanner class am stuck, I need to get d particular key pressed by the user, and pass it in to the voice synthesis engine for it to say d particular letter pressed

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question so I can only give a little bit of help. To get you started, you should use the basic `java.util.Scanner`that is used for most keyboard input readers.

You would have to import at least these two tools like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;  //reads input from keys
import java.speech.Engine; //allows java to "speak"
```

An alternative for the Scanner tool is BufferReader or KeyboardReader. However, I suggest Scanner because it is easiest to use and is built-in with java.

The rest of how to use the speaking Engine in java you can find here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-text-speech-java/

Hope this helps :)