# How can I change this to be able to get the filename from a user's input in java?

Tags: java

This is what i have, i just pass in the filename in this, but i want to be able to get the filename from the user.

```
try {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner (Paths.get("PostalCodeRecord.txt"));
        while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String dataLine = inFile.nextLine();
            if (dataLine.length()>6){
                Scanner line = new Scanner (dataLine);
                String month = line.next();
```

Comment: For a GUI thing, try with JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null)

Comment: You can create a `Scanner` to read from the console and then save the filename to a variable. Take a look at the example in the answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java/31241089).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create another Scanner object and ask for the file name from the user and store it in a string variable. Then you use that in your file scanner

```
 try {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter file name");
    String fileName = scan.nextLine();
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner (Paths.get(fileName));
    while (inFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String dataLine = inFile.nextLine();
        if (dataLine.length()>6){
            Scanner line = new Scanner (dataLine);
            String month = line.next();
```