# How to fix a java function

Tags: java

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong on the code below?  I will appreciate it! I am getting the error "incompatible types: double cannot be converted into double[].

```
public class AverageFunction {
    public static double mean(double[] a) { 
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            sum += a[i];
        return sum / a.length;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] a = StdIn.readDouble();
    double result = mean(a);
    StdOut.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: First you should tell us how you know that something is wrong: Does the code not compile? Does it produce an Error when running it? Does it produce wrong results?

Comment: What is wrong with the code? Compiler error? If so: please include the error. Unexpected behaviour? If so: please include expected and observed behaviour. An exception? If so: please include the stack trace.

Comment: Can you also tell what is the error while executing the above code?

Comment: You never define what `StdIn` or `StdOut` is. And the rest of the line `double[] a = StdIn.readDouble();` looks troubling as well.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java

Comment: `double[] a = StdIn.readDouble();` you are reading a single double but you try to store it as an array of double

Comment: Dear jhamon,  Thank you very much for your time and for answering the question.  I do appreciate it!

Comment: @jhamon you should write that as an answer if this gets re-opened and earn the reputation for being helpful

Answer (score 0):

The `readDouble()` method only read a single double.

Your are trying to assign the returned value to an array of double. The types mismatch.

To read multiple double, you can use the `readAllDoubles()` method. Check the [javadoc](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdIn.html#readAllDoubles--) (I can't find any other source for this library) for more informations.