# How do I get the Scanner in java to read a string?

Tags: java, string, loops, integer, java.util.scanner

How would I get my program to quit when the user enters q?
Is there something wrong with the scanner?

---

My code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{

         public static void main(String []args){
             
             int age;
             
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter your age, or enter 'q' to quit the program.");
            age = scan.nextInt();
            
            
            if(age.equals("q") || age.equals("Q")){
                
                return 0;
                
            }
            
            
            
            System.out.println("Your age is " + age);
            
            
            
         }
    
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but I also want it to read integers.

Comment: Then `age.equals("any string")` will never be true and `.equals` is not a method of an `int`

Comment: Then what are the workarounds to get the integer, but when a user enters the string q it ends the program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see mainly two problems in your code:

1. It lacks a loop to repeat asking for age again. There can be many ways (`for`, `while`, `do-while`) to write a loop but I find [`do-while`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) most appropriate for such a case as it always executes the statements within the `do` block at least once.
2. `age` is of type, `int` and therefore it can not be compared with a string e.g. your code, `age.equals("q")` is not correct. A good way to handle such a situation is to get the input into a variable of type, `String` and check the value if it should allow/disallow processing it (e.g. trying to parse it into an `int`).

Note that when you try to parse a string which can not be parsed into an `int` (e.g. `"a"`), you get a `NumberFormatException` which you need to handle (e.g. show an error message, change some state etc.).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int age;
        String input;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean valid;

        do {
            // Start with the assumption that input will be valid
            valid = true;
            System.out.print("Enter your age, or enter 'q' to quit the program: ");
            input = scan.nextLine();

            if (!(input.equals("q") || input.equals("Q"))) {
                try {
                    // Try to parse input into an int
                    age = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    System.out.println("Your age is " + age);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
                    // Change the value of valid to false
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        } while (!valid || !(input.equals("q") || input.equals("Q")));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter your age, or enter 'q' to quit the program: a
Invalid input
Enter your age, or enter 'q' to quit the program: 12.5
Invalid input
Enter your age, or enter 'q' to quit the program: 14
Your age is 14
Enter your age, or enter 'q' to quit the program: 56
Your age is 56
Enter your age, or enter 'q' to quit the program: q
```

Comment: Please *explain* this answer

Comment: Please see [Are answers that contain only commented code acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310219/are-answers-that-contain-only-commented-code-acceptable)