# How do I use arguments sent to the program in a class other than the main class?

Tags: java, string, file, oop, linked-list

My program consists of 2 classes named `Main` and `LinkedList` and my program takes 3 arguments. For example, while I can access `args[1]` in the Main class, I cannot access it in the LinkedList class. It says array access `args[2]` will produce `NullPointerException` and If I try to run it, it gaves me `NullPointerException`. How can I solve this?

Here is my code:

Main Cass:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner; // Import the Scanner class to read text files


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int i = 0;
        /* Start with the empty list. */
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList(args);
        int id1 = 0,year1 = 0,count1 = 0,price1 = 0;
        String name1 = "",singer1 = "";

        //The contents of data.txt have been loaded into the program.
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[1]));
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

                String data = scan.nextLine();
                String[] readedData = data.split(";");
                LinkedList.insert(list,id1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[0]),price1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[1]),name1 = readedData[2],singer1 = readedData[3],year1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[4]),count1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[5]));
            }
            scan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //The object required to write to the file has been created.
        //FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(args[2]);
        PrintStream output = new PrintStream(args[2]);

        //The input.txt file has started to be read.
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = scan.nextLine();

                // First, split on whitespace
                //String[] parts = data.split("(?<!\"\\w\")\\s+(?!\\w+\")"); //Alternate Solution

                String[] parts = data.split("\\s(?=\\w+:)");
                String[] parts1 = data.split("(?<!\"\\w\")\\s+(?!\\w+\")");
                String command1 = parts1[0];

                // The first element in the array is the command
                String command = parts[0];
                // Split the remaining elements on ':'
                String[] keyVal;
                String key = " ";
                String value= " ";
                for (i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
                    keyVal = parts[i].split(":");
                    if (keyVal.length == 2) {
                        key = keyVal[0];
                        value = keyVal[1];
                        switch (key) {
                            case "id" -> id1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                            case "name" -> name1 = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1);
                            case "singer" -> singer1 = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1);
                            case "year" -> year1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                            case "count" -> count1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                            case "price" -> price1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                switch (command1) {
                    case "Add" -> {
                        LinkedList.insert(list, id1, price1, name1, singer1, year1, count1);                //DONE!
                        output.print("New CD added id: "+id1+" name: "+name1);
                        output.println();
                    }
                    case "Search" -> {
                        output.print("List:\n");
                        String[] key1 = command.split(" ");
                        String SearchKey = key1[1];
                        SearchKey = SearchKey.substring(1, SearchKey.length() - 1);
                        LinkedList.searchAndFind(list,SearchKey);
                    }
                    case "Remove" -> {
                        LinkedList.deleteNode(list,LinkedList.searchPosition(list,id1));                  //DONE!
                        output.print("CD removed id: "+id1);
                        output.println();
                    }
                    case "List" -> {
                        output.print("List:\n");
                        LinkedList.printList(list);                                                       //DONE!
                    }
                    case "Edit" -> {
                        output.print("Edit CD id: "+id1);
                        output.println();
                        switch (key) {
                            case "singer" -> LinkedList.editSinger(list, id1, singer1);
                            case "name" -> LinkedList.editName(list, id1, name1);
                            case "year" -> LinkedList.editYear(list, id1, year1);                         //DONE!
                            case "count" -> LinkedList.editCount(list, id1, count1);
                            case "price" -> LinkedList.editPrice(list, id1, price1);
                        }
                    }
                    case ("Sell") -> {
                        LinkedList.sell(list,id1);
                        output.print("CD Sold. ID: "+id1);                                                //DONE!
                        output.println();
                    }
                    case "Quit" -> {
                        output.print("Quit");
                        output.println();
                        output.print("Cash :"+LinkedList.cash);
                        output.println();
                    }
                }
            }
            output.close();
            scan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //LinkedList.printList(list);
    }
}
```

LinkedList Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class LinkedList {

    Node head; // head of list

    private String[] args;
    public LinkedList(String[] args) throws IOException {
        this.args = args;
    }
    
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(args[2]); //=====> PROBLEM İS HERE!
    static class Node {

        int id;
        int year;
        int count;
        int price;
        String name;
        String singer;

        Node next;

        // Constructor
        Node(int i, int p, String n, String s, int y, int c) {
            id = i;
            year = y;
            count = c;
            price = p;
            name = n;
            singer = s;

            next = null;
        }
    }

    public static LinkedList insert(LinkedList list, int i,int p, String n, String s, int y,int c)
    {
        // Create a new node with given data
        Node new_node = new Node(i,p,n,s,y,c);
        new_node.next = null;

        // If the Linked List is empty,
        // then make the new node as head
        if (list.head == null) {
            list.head = new_node;
        }
        else {
            // Else traverse till the last node
            // and insert the new_node there
            Node last = list.head;
            while (last.next != null) {
                last = last.next;
            }

            // Insert the new_node at last node
            last.next = new_node;
        }

        // Return the list by head
        return list;
    }

    public static void printList(LinkedList list)
    {
        Node currNode = list.head;

        System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
        System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        // Traverse through the LinkedList
        while (currNode != null) {
            // Print the data at current node
            System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", currNode.id, currNode.price, currNode.name, currNode.singer, currNode.year, currNode.count);

            // Go to next node
            currNode = currNode.next;
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void deleteNode(LinkedList list ,int position)
    {
        // If linked list is empty
        if (list.head == null)
            return;

        // Store head node
        Node temp = list.head;

        // If head needs to be removed
        if (position == 0)
        {
            list.head = temp.next;   // Change head
            return;
        }

        // Find previous node of the node to be deleted
        for (int i=0; temp!=null && i<position-1; i++)
            temp = temp.next;

        // If position is more than number of nodes
        if (temp == null || temp.next == null)
            return;

        // Node temp->next is the node to be deleted
        // Store pointer to the next of node to be deleted
        Node next = temp.next.next;

        temp.next = next;  // Unlink the deleted node from list
    }

    static int search = 0;
    static int cash = 0;
    public static int searchPosition(LinkedList list, int x)
    {
        search = 0;
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
            search++;
        }
        return search;
    }

    public static int sell(LinkedList list, int x)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                cash = cash + current.price;
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        return cash;
    }

    public static void editName(LinkedList list, int x, String a)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.name = a;
                System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }

    }
    public static void editSinger(LinkedList list, int x, String a)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.singer = a;
                System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    public static void editYear(LinkedList list, int x, int a)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.year = a;
                System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    public static void editCount(LinkedList list, int x, int a)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.count = a;
                System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    public static void editPrice(LinkedList list, int x, int a)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.price = a;
                System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    public static void searchAndFind(LinkedList list, String a)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
        System.out.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.name.contains(a)){
                System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                System.out.println();
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [no pictures of exceptions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/) / [no pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Then use the [edit] link to replace screen shots of text with nicely formatted/indented text within your question.

Comment: And your problem is straight forward: the variable *args* isn't defined in that class where you try to use it. You cant just point to a **parameter** that another class receives as argument to some method. Instead: that OTHER class has to *somehow* pass it to the class that needs it!

Comment: Write your output file using a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) ; anything you could do on `System.out` you can also do on that `PrintStream`.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, I was thinking this too, but I couldn't send it from the Main class to the LinkedList class. How can I do that ?

Comment: Just one idea: step back then. It sounds like you are trying to solve "java lesson no. 8", while your skill is at level 3 or so. You have to think from the perspective of the MAIN method. That method takes command line args from the command line, and then creates the objects needed to do what is necessary.

Comment: Meaning: maybe you should try to do less advanced examples for now. Or well, sit down and re-do the previous classes.

Comment: @GhostCat I tried something new by reviewing what you told and I think it works. The only drawback is that inside the LinkedList class, it says args [2] will return NullPointerException. What is the reason? Can you check pls? I updated my code above.

Comment: @KevinAnderson I tried something new by reviewing what you told and I think it works. The only drawback is that inside the LinkedList class, it says args [2] will return NullPointerException. What is the reason? Can you check pls? I updated my code above.

Comment: @Roxox - I didn't understand what you need `output` for. By the way, you can Replace

    `public LinkedList(String[] args) throws IOException {
        this.args = args;
    }
    
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(args[2]); //=====> PROBLEM İS HERE!`


with

    `PrintStream output = null;
    
    public LinkedList(String[] args) throws IOException {
        this.args = args;
        output = new PrintStream(args[2]); 
    }`

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash For example, when the List command is read, the printList function inside the LinkedList works. This function should print the information contained in LinkedList to my output.txt file. I had already created an object called output inside the Main class that allows me to write to the file. Can I use this object from the LinkedList class, or do I need to define a new object as I am trying to do? In summary, I need to write everything I previously printed on the console with System.out.println to a file.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash So I'll exchange output.print and System.out.println. I set it up like you said, but this time the output object currently running in my Main class is broken. The whole program is up and running, but writing errors are seriously annoying. I have no idea what to do: /

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I think when I create 2 write objects running on args [2] and try to use them, there is a conflict and the output.printf commands in my Main class do not work.

Comment: @Roxox - I feel very bad that when you need my help, I am too much occupied with work today. I managed a few minutes to read your code but it's long and therefore I could not analyse it properly. I suggest you edit the question and add four sections: (1) What is your requirement (2) How you are running your program e.g. `java Main abc.txt xyz.txt` (3) What is the expected behaviour (4) What is the actual behaviour. This will help other contributors understand the problem clearly and I'm sure someone will post the required solution.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thank you for your help sir. I will try to open a new question by following your instructions. I hope I can fix the problem.

Comment: Please note: this here isn't a free tutoring service. People come here, ask one clear question and get answer to that. This place is not intended to sit down with you to walk you through your homework. You should try to do as much as possible alone. If you need people to help out, then ask your peers, tutors, instructors. But please be careful about asking more questions in comments.

Comment: @GhostCat If I did something wrong I'm sorry. I'm just beginner at CS and trying to learn things as much as possible.

Comment: I understand. But you really want to look at the [help] to learn how and what to ask here. This place has its rules. And one part of learning programming is how to research things yourself and how to best facilitate resources like this community here!

Comment: I solved it. Here is my solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64652825/14537190

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, the String array `args` is part of the main method of **Main.java**.

> How can I create an object to write to files in my LinkedList class

What you can do, is to change the constructor of **LinkedList.java** to ...

```
public LinkedList(String[] args) throws IOException {
     this.args = args;
}
```

... and use it in your class, but we will use an PrintStream, because it also has all of the methods of course. `printf()`, `println()`, and so on ...

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException;

public class LinkedList {
    Node head; // head of list

    private String[] args;        

    public LinkedList(String[] args) throws IOException {
         this.args = args;
    }

static class Node {

    int id;
    int year;
    int count;
    int price;
    String name;
    String singer;

    Node next;

    // Constructor
    Node(int i, int p, String n, String s, int y, int c) {
        id = i;
        year = y;
        count = c;
        price = p;
        name = n;
        singer = s;

        next = null;
    }
}

public static LinkedList insert(LinkedList list, int i,int p, String n, String s, int y,int c)
{
    // Create a new node with given data
    Node new_node = new Node(i,p,n,s,y,c);
    new_node.next = null;

    // If the Linked List is empty,
    // then make the new node as head
    if (list.head == null) {
        list.head = new_node;
    }
    else {
        // Else traverse till the last node
        // and insert the new_node there
        Node last = list.head;
        while (last.next != null) {
            last = last.next;
        }

        // Insert the new_node at last node
        last.next = new_node;
    }

    // Return the list by head
    return list;
}

public static void printList(LinkedList list)
{
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(args[2])));
    Node currNode = list.head;

    writer.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
    writer.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    // Traverse through the LinkedList
    while (currNode != null) {
        // Print the data at current node
        writer.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", currNode.id, currNode.price, currNode.name, currNode.singer, currNode.year, currNode.count);

        // Go to next node
        currNode = currNode.next;
        writer.println();
    }
    writer.println();
}

public static void deleteNode(LinkedList list ,int position)
{
    // If linked list is empty
    if (list.head == null)
        return;

    // Store head node
    Node temp = list.head;

    // If head needs to be removed
    if (position == 0)
    {
        list.head = temp.next;   // Change head
        return;
    }

    // Find previous node of the node to be deleted
    for (int i=0; temp!=null && i<position-1; i++)
        temp = temp.next;

    // If position is more than number of nodes
    if (temp == null || temp.next == null)
        return;

    // Node temp->next is the node to be deleted
    // Store pointer to the next of node to be deleted
    Node next = temp.next.next;

    temp.next = next;  // Unlink the deleted node from list
}

static int search = 0;
static int cash = 0;
public static int searchPosition(LinkedList list, int x)
{
    search = 0;
    Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.id == x){
            break;
        }
        current = current.next;
        search++;
    }
    return search;
}

public static int sell(LinkedList list, int x)
{
    Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.id == x){
            cash = cash + current.price;
            break;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    return cash;
}

public static void editName(LinkedList list, int x, String a)
{
    Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.id == x){
            current.name = a;
            break;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
}
public static void editSinger(LinkedList list, int x, String a)
{
    Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.id == x){
            current.singer = a;
            break;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
}
public static void editYear(LinkedList list, int x, int a)
{
    Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.id == x){
            current.year = a;
            break;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
}
public static void editCount(LinkedList list, int x, int a)
{
    Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.id == x){
            current.count = a;
            break;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
}
public static void editPrice(LinkedList list, int x, int a)
{
    Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.id == x){
            current.price = a;
            break;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
}
public static void searchAndFind(LinkedList list, String a)
{
    Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(args[2])));

    writer.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
    writer.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    while (current != null)
    {
        if (current.name.contains(a)){
            System.out.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
            System.out.println();
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
}
}
```

And your main then:

```
import java.io.File;  // Import the File class
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  // Import this class to handle errors
import java.util.Scanner; // Import the Scanner class to read text files
import java.io.FileWriter;   // Import the FileWriter class
import java.io.IOException;  // Import the IOException class to handle errors

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int i = 0;
    /* Start with the empty list. */
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList(args);
    int id1 = 0,year1 = 0,count1 = 0,price1 = 0;
    String name1 = "",singer1 = "";

    //The contents of data.txt have been loaded into the program.
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[1]));
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

            String data = scan.nextLine();
            String[] readedData = data.split(";");
            LinkedList.insert(list,id1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[0]),price1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[1]),name1 = readedData[2],singer1 = readedData[3],year1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[4]),count1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[5]));
        }
        scan.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //The object required to write to the file has been created.
    FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(args[2]);

    //The input.txt file has started to be read.
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String data = scan.nextLine();

            // First, split on whitespace
            //String[] parts = data.split("(?<!\"\\w\")\\s+(?!\\w+\")"); //Alternate Solution

            String[] parts = data.split("\\s(?=\\w+:)");
            String[] parts1 = data.split("(?<!\"\\w\")\\s+(?!\\w+\")");
            String command1 = parts1[0];

            // The first element in the array is the command
            String command = parts[0];
            // Split the remaining elements on ':'
            String[] keyVal;
            String key = " ";
            String value= " ";
            for (i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
                keyVal = parts[i].split(":");
                if (keyVal.length == 2) {
                    key = keyVal[0];
                    value = keyVal[1];
                    switch (key) {
                        case "id" -> id1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                        case "name" -> name1 = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1);
                        case "singer" -> singer1 = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1);
                        case "year" -> year1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                        case "count" -> count1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                        case "price" -> price1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                    }
                }
            }
            switch (command1) {
                case "Add" -> {
                    LinkedList.insert(list, id1, price1, name1, singer1, year1, count1);                //DONE!
                    myWriter.write("New CD added id: "+id1+" name: "+name1);
                }
                case "Search" -> {
                    String[] key1 = command.split(" ");
                    String SearchKey = key1[1];
                    SearchKey = SearchKey.substring(1, SearchKey.length() - 1);
                    LinkedList.searchAndFind(list,SearchKey);
                }
                case "Remove" -> {
                    LinkedList.deleteNode(list,LinkedList.searchPosition(list,id1));                  //DONE!
                    myWriter.write("CD removed id: "+id1);
                }
                case "List" -> {
                    LinkedList.printList(list);                                                       //DONE!
                }
                case "Edit" -> {
                    switch (key) {
                        case "singer" -> LinkedList.editSinger(list, id1, singer1);
                        case "name" -> LinkedList.editName(list, id1, name1);
                        case "year" -> LinkedList.editYear(list, id1, year1);                         //DONE!
                        case "count" -> LinkedList.editCount(list, id1, count1);
                        case "price" -> LinkedList.editPrice(list, id1, price1);
                    }
                }
                case ("Sell") -> {
                    LinkedList.sell(list,id1);
                    myWriter.write("CD Sold. ID: "+id1);                                              //DONE!
                }
                case "Quit" -> {
                    myWriter.write("Quit");
                    myWriter.write(LinkedList.cash);
                }
            }
        }
        myWriter.close();
        scan.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //LinkedList.printList(list);
}
}
```

Comment: I tried something new by reviewing what you told and I think it works. The only drawback is that inside the LinkedList class, it says args [2] will return NullPointerException. What is the reason? I updated my code above.

Comment: Because args[2] could also be null, so it could throw NullPointerException. What you can do is, `if(args[2] != null) {`