# Weird problem about writing a file in Java

Tags: java, file, oop, linked-list, arguments

When starting my program it takes 3 arguments named `input.txt`, `data.txt` and `output.txt`. It saves the information of the songs in the `data.txt` to the `LinkedList` and performs operations by processing the commands in the `input.txt`. Some commands in `input.txt` (eg List) print information to the `output.txt` file.

Content of input.txt:

```
Add id:12 name:"Sandik" singer:"Muslum Gurses" year:2009 count:5 price:20
Add id:15 singer:"Tarkan" name:"Adimi Kalbine Yaz" year:2010 count:10 price:20
Add id:20 name:"Fear of the Dark" singer:"Iron Maiden" year:1992 count:20 price:15
Add id:25 name:"Dark Side of the moon" singer:"Almora" year:1987 count:5 price:10
Remove id:12
List
Edit id:15 singer:"Tarkan Tevetoglu"
Search "ark"
Sell 20
List
Quit
```

Content of data.txt:

```
<id>; <price>; <name>; <singer>; <year>; <count>

15;20;Adimi Kalbine Yaz; Tarkan Tevetoglu;2010;10
12;20;Sandik;Muslum Gurses;2009;5
20;15;Fear of the Dark;Iron Maiden;1992;20
```

Expected output.txt:

```
New CD added id: 12 name:"Sandik"
New CD added id: 15 name:"Adimi Kalbine Yaz"
New CD added id: 20 name:"Fear of the Dark"
New CD added id: 25 name:"Dark Side of the moon"
CD removed id: 12


List (12 is removed)
Id   Price                     Name         Singer      Year      Count
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
15      20        Adimi Kalbine Yaz         Tarkan      2010         10
25      10    Dark Side of the moon         Almora      1984          5
20      20         Fear of the Dark    Iron Maiden      1992         20


Edit CD id: 15
Id   Price                     Name              Singer      Year      Count
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
15      20        Adimi Kalbine Yaz    Tarkan Tevetoglu      2010         10


Id   Price                     Name         Singer      Year      Count
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
15      20        Adimi Kalbine Yaz         Tarkan      2010         10
25      10    Dark Side of the moon         Almora      1984          5
20      20         Fear of the Dark    Iron Maiden      1992         20


Search "ark”
Id   Price                     Name         Singer      Year      Count
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
25      10    Dark Side of the moon         Almora      1984          5
20      20         Fear of the Dark    Iron Maiden      1992         20


CD sold id: 20
Id   Price                     Name         Singer      Year      Count
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
15      20        Adimi Kalbine Yaz         Tarkan      2010         10
25      10    Dark Side of the moon         Almora      1984          5
20      20         Fear of the Dark    Iron Maiden      1992         20


Quit
Cash: 20
Best Seller: Fear of the Dark
```

My program consists of 2 classes, `Main` and `LinkedList`. I wrote this program and everything is ok. However, while the program was being developed, I was doing my experiments on the console. I finished the program and while I was changing the print parts to print to the file instead of the console, my program exploded. Before I explain the part that causes the problem, I want to share my code.

Main Class :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner; // Import the Scanner class to read text files


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int i = 0;
        /* Start with the empty list. */
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList(args);
        int id1 = 0,year1 = 0,count1 = 0,price1 = 0;
        String name1 = "",singer1 = "";

        //The contents of data.txt have been loaded into the program.
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[1]));
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

                String data = scan.nextLine();
                String[] readedData = data.split(";");
                LinkedList.insert(list,id1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[0]),price1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[1]),name1 = readedData[2],singer1 = readedData[3],year1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[4]),count1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[5]));
            }
            scan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //The object required to write to the file has been created.
        //FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(args[2]);
        PrintStream output1 = new PrintStream(args[2]);

        //The input.txt file has started to be read.
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = scan.nextLine();

                // First, split on whitespace
                //String[] parts = data.split("(?<!\"\\w\")\\s+(?!\\w+\")"); //Alternate Solution

                String[] parts = data.split("\\s(?=\\w+:)");
                String[] parts1 = data.split("(?<!\"\\w\")\\s+(?!\\w+\")");
                String command1 = parts1[0];

                // The first element in the array is the command
                String command = parts[0];
                // Split the remaining elements on ':'
                String[] keyVal;
                String key = " ";
                String value= " ";
                for (i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
                    keyVal = parts[i].split(":");
                    if (keyVal.length == 2) {
                        key = keyVal[0];
                        value = keyVal[1];
                        switch (key) {
                            case "id" -> id1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                            case "name" -> name1 = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1);
                            case "singer" -> singer1 = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1);
                            case "year" -> year1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                            case "count" -> count1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                            case "price" -> price1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                switch (command1) {
                    case "Add" -> {
                        LinkedList.insert(list, id1, price1, name1, singer1, year1, count1);                //DONE!
                        output1.print("New CD added id: "+id1+" name: "+name1);
                        output1.println();
                    }
                    case "Search" -> {
                        output1.print("List:\n");
                        String[] key1 = command.split(" ");
                        String SearchKey = key1[1];
                        SearchKey = SearchKey.substring(1, SearchKey.length() - 1);
                        LinkedList.searchAndFind(list,SearchKey);
                        output1.println();
                    }
                    case "Remove" -> {
                        LinkedList.deleteNode(list,LinkedList.searchPosition(list,id1));                  //DONE!
                        output1.print("CD removed id: "+id1);
                        output1.println();
                    }
                    case "List" -> {
                        output1.print("List:\n");
                        LinkedList.printList(list);
                        output1.println();
                    }
                    case "Edit" -> {
                        output1.print("Edit CD id: "+id1);
                        output1.println();
                        switch (key) {
                            case "singer" -> LinkedList.editSinger(list, id1, singer1);
                            case "name" -> LinkedList.editName(list, id1, name1);
                            case "year" -> LinkedList.editYear(list, id1, year1);                         //DONE!
                            case "count" -> LinkedList.editCount(list, id1, count1);
                            case "price" -> LinkedList.editPrice(list, id1, price1);
                        }
                        output1.println();
                    }
                    case ("Sell") -> {
                        LinkedList.sell(list,id1);
                        output1.print("CD Sold. ID: "+id1);                                                //DONE!
                        output1.println();
                    }
                    case "Quit" -> {
                        output1.print("Quit");
                        output1.println();
                        output1.print("Cash :"+LinkedList.cash);
                        output1.println();
                    }
                }
            }
            scan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        output1.close();
    }
}
```

LinkedList Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class LinkedList {

    Node head; // head of list

    public String[] args;

    static PrintStream output = null;
    public LinkedList(String[] args) throws IOException {
        this.args = args;
        output = new PrintStream(args[2]);
    }

    static class Node {

        int id;
        int year;
        int count;
        int price;
        String name;
        String singer;

        Node next;

        // Constructor
        Node(int i, int p, String n, String s, int y, int c) {
            id = i;
            year = y;
            count = c;
            price = p;
            name = n;
            singer = s;

            next = null;
        }
    }

    public static LinkedList insert(LinkedList list, int i,int p, String n, String s, int y,int c)
    {
        // Create a new node with given data
        Node new_node = new Node(i,p,n,s,y,c);
        new_node.next = null;

        // If the Linked List is empty,
        // then make the new node as head
        if (list.head == null) {
            list.head = new_node;
        }
        else {
            // Else traverse till the last node
            // and insert the new_node there
            Node last = list.head;
            while (last.next != null) {
                last = last.next;
            }

            // Insert the new_node at last node
            last.next = new_node;
        }

        // Return the list by head
        return list;
    }

    public static void printList(LinkedList list)
    {
        Node currNode = list.head;

        output.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
        output.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        // Traverse through the LinkedList
        while (currNode != null) {
            // Print the data at current node
            output.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", currNode.id, currNode.price, currNode.name, currNode.singer, currNode.year, currNode.count);

            // Go to next node
            currNode = currNode.next;
            output.println();
        }
        output.println();
    }

    public static void deleteNode(LinkedList list ,int position)
    {
        // If linked list is empty
        if (list.head == null)
            return;

        // Store head node
        Node temp = list.head;

        // If head needs to be removed
        if (position == 0)
        {
            list.head = temp.next;   // Change head
            return;
        }

        // Find previous node of the node to be deleted
        for (int i=0; temp!=null && i<position-1; i++)
            temp = temp.next;

        // If position is more than number of nodes
        if (temp == null || temp.next == null)
            return;

        // Node temp->next is the node to be deleted
        // Store pointer to the next of node to be deleted
        Node next = temp.next.next;

        temp.next = next;  // Unlink the deleted node from list
    }

    static int search = 0;
    static int cash = 0;
    public static int searchPosition(LinkedList list, int x)
    {
        search = 0;
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
            search++;
        }
        return search;
    }

    public static int sell(LinkedList list, int x)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                cash = cash + current.price;
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        return cash;
    }

    public static void editName(LinkedList list, int x, String a)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.name = a;
                output.printf("\n\n%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                output.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                output.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }

    }
    public static void editSinger(LinkedList list, int x, String a)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.singer = a;
                output.printf("\n\n%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                output.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                output.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    public static void editYear(LinkedList list, int x, int a)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.year = a;
                output.printf("\n\n%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                output.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                output.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    public static void editCount(LinkedList list, int x, int a)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.count = a;
                output.printf("\n\n%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                output.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                output.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    public static void editPrice(LinkedList list, int x, int a)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.price = a;
                output.printf("\n\n%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                output.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                output.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    public static void searchAndFind(LinkedList list, String a)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        output.printf("\n\n%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
        output.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.name.contains(a)){
                output.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                output.println();
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

When I ran the program, the output printed to the output.txt file was incorrect and I debugged it. When my program came to the switch structure, the first command, add, was read and the operation was performed, everything was fine. Until the `List` command is read. All commands before the `List` command worked fine and everything was fine, but when `List` was read, the `printList` function from the `LinkedList` class worked. As soon as this line runs, my `output.txt` file gets corrupted. `output.printf ("% s% 10s% 30s% 25s% 15s% 10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");`

And every time the `output.print` command in the `LinkedList` class ran, my `output.txt` file was further corrupted. I think the problem may be caused by 2 separate objects writing on the same file. I'm not sure, but they may be conflicting. How can I solve this problem or is there a more practical way? I would be grateful if you could help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For example, I solved the problem by sending the object named output1 that I created in Main to the function that will be called when the add command is read and using it in the LinkedList class.

LinkedList Class:

```
import java.io.*;

public class LinkedList {
    Node head; // head of list

    public String[] args;

    public LinkedList(String[] args){
        this.args = args;
    }

    static class Node {

        int id;
        int year;
        int count;
        int price;
        String name;
        String singer;

        Node next;

        // Constructor
        Node(int i, int p, String n, String s, int y, int c) {
            id = i;
            year = y;
            count = c;
            price = p;
            name = n;
            singer = s;

            next = null;
        }
    }

    public static LinkedList insert(LinkedList list, int i,int p, String n, String s, int y,int c)
    {
        // Create a new node with given data
        Node new_node = new Node(i,p,n,s,y,c);
        new_node.next = null;

        // If the Linked List is empty,
        // then make the new node as head
        if (list.head == null) {
            list.head = new_node;
        }
        else {
            // Else traverse till the last node
            // and insert the new_node there
            Node last = list.head;
            while (last.next != null) {
                last = last.next;
            }

            // Insert the new_node at last node
            last.next = new_node;
        }

        // Return the list by head
        return list;
    }

    public static void printList(LinkedList list, PrintStream x)
    {
        Node currNode = list.head;

        x.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
        x.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        // Traverse through the LinkedList
        while (currNode != null) {
            // Print the data at current node
            x.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", currNode.id, currNode.price, currNode.name, currNode.singer, currNode.year, currNode.count);

            // Go to next node
            currNode = currNode.next;
            x.println();
        }
        x.println();
    }

    public static void deleteNode(LinkedList list ,int position)
    {
        // If linked list is empty
        if (list.head == null)
            return;

        // Store head node
        Node temp = list.head;

        // If head needs to be removed
        if (position == 0)
        {
            list.head = temp.next;   // Change head
            return;
        }

        // Find previous node of the node to be deleted
        for (int i=0; temp!=null && i<position-1; i++)
            temp = temp.next;

        // If position is more than number of nodes
        if (temp == null || temp.next == null)
            return;

        // Node temp->next is the node to be deleted
        // Store pointer to the next of node to be deleted
        Node next = temp.next.next;

        temp.next = next;  // Unlink the deleted node from list
    }

    static int search = 0;
    static int cash = 0;
    public static int searchPosition(LinkedList list, int x)
    {
        search = 0;
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
            search++;
        }
        return search;
    }

    public static int sell(LinkedList list, int x)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                cash = cash + current.price;
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
        return cash;
    }

    public static void editName(LinkedList list, int x, String a, PrintStream y)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.name = a;
                y.printf("\n\n%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                y.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                y.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }

    }
    public static void editSinger(LinkedList list, int x, String a, PrintStream y)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.singer = a;
                y.printf("\n\n%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                y.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                y.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    public static void editYear(LinkedList list, int x, int a, PrintStream y)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.year = a;
                y.printf("\n\n%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                y.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                y.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    public static void editCount(LinkedList list, int x, int a, PrintStream y)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.count = a;
                y.printf("\n\n%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                y.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                y.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    public static void editPrice(LinkedList list, int x, int a, PrintStream y)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.id == x){
                current.price = a;
                y.printf("\n\n%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
                y.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                y.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
    public static void searchAndFind(LinkedList list, String a, PrintStream y)
    {
        Node current = list.head;    //Initialize current
        y.printf("\n\n%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", "ID", "Price", "Name", "Singer", "Year", "Count");
        y.println("\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.name.contains(a)){
                y.printf("%s %10s %30s %25s %15s %10s", current.id, current.price, current.name, current.singer, current.year, current.count);
                y.println();
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner; // Import the Scanner class to read text files


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int i = 0;
        /* Start with the empty list. */
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList(args);
        int id1 = 0,year1 = 0,count1 = 0,price1 = 0;
        String name1 = "",singer1 = "";

        //The contents of data.txt have been loaded into the program.
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[1]));
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {

                String data = scan.nextLine();
                String[] readedData = data.split(";");
                LinkedList.insert(list,id1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[0]),price1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[1]),name1 = readedData[2],singer1 = readedData[3],year1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[4]),count1 = Integer.parseInt(readedData[5]));
            }
            scan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //The object required to write to the file has been created.
        //FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(args[2]);
        PrintStream output1 = new PrintStream(args[2]);

        //The input.txt file has started to be read.
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = scan.nextLine();

                // First, split on whitespace
                //String[] parts = data.split("(?<!\"\\w\")\\s+(?!\\w+\")"); //Alternate Solution

                String[] parts = data.split("\\s(?=\\w+:)");
                String[] parts1 = data.split("(?<!\"\\w\")\\s+(?!\\w+\")");
                String command1 = parts1[0];

                // The first element in the array is the command
                String command = parts[0];
                // Split the remaining elements on ':'
                String[] keyVal;
                String key = " ";
                String value= " ";
                for (i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
                    keyVal = parts[i].split(":");
                    if (keyVal.length == 2) {
                        key = keyVal[0];
                        value = keyVal[1];
                        switch (key) {
                            case "id" -> id1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                            case "name" -> name1 = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1);
                            case "singer" -> singer1 = value.substring(1, value.length() - 1);
                            case "year" -> year1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                            case "count" -> count1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                            case "price" -> price1 = Integer.parseInt(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                switch (command1) {
                    case "Add" -> {
                        LinkedList.insert(list, id1, price1, name1, singer1, year1, count1);                //DONE!
                        output1.print("New CD added id: "+id1+" name: "+name1);
                        output1.println();
                    }
                    case "Search" -> {
                        output1.print("List:\n");
                        String[] key1 = command.split(" ");
                        String SearchKey = key1[1];
                        SearchKey = SearchKey.substring(1, SearchKey.length() - 1);
                        LinkedList.searchAndFind(list,SearchKey,output1);
                        output1.println();
                    }
                    case "Remove" -> {
                        LinkedList.deleteNode(list,LinkedList.searchPosition(list,id1));                  //DONE!
                        output1.print("CD removed id: "+id1);
                        output1.println();
                    }
                    case "List" -> {
                        output1.print("List:\n");
                        LinkedList.printList(list,output1);
                        output1.println();
                    }
                    case "Edit" -> {
                        output1.print("Edit CD id: "+id1);
                        output1.println();
                        switch (key) {
                            case "singer" -> LinkedList.editSinger(list, id1, singer1,output1);
                            case "name" -> LinkedList.editName(list, id1, name1,output1);
                            case "year" -> LinkedList.editYear(list, id1, year1,output1);                         //DONE!
                            case "count" -> LinkedList.editCount(list, id1, count1,output1);
                            case "price" -> LinkedList.editPrice(list, id1, price1,output1);
                        }
                        output1.println();
                    }
                    case ("Sell") -> {
                        LinkedList.sell(list,id1);
                        output1.print("CD Sold. ID: "+id1);                                                //DONE!
                        output1.println();
                    }
                    case "Quit" -> {
                        output1.print("Quit");
                        output1.println();
                        output1.print("Cash :"+LinkedList.cash);
                        output1.println();
                    }
                }
            }
            scan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        output1.close();
    }
}
```