# How do use console to choose any file from a folder?

Tags: java, filechooser, console-input

I need to be able to choose any file inside a folder by input on console.

#### Code

Instead of a predefined like `"bridge_rgb.png"` I want to be able to choose any file in the folder via console input.

```java
private void imageName() {
        System.out.println("Select your image");
        String input = scanner.next();
        if (input.equals("bridge_rgb.png")) {

        } else if (input.equals("gmit_rgb.png")) {
        
        }

        System.out.println("Image Selected");

    }
```

Inside my functions I want to do the same, here's the code:

```java
File file = new File("bridge_rgb.png");
BufferedImage source = ImageIO.read(file);

// processing: result gets created

File output = new File("bridge_grey.png");
ImageIO.write(result, "png", output);
```

I know a GUI would make file-choosing easy, but I have to use specifically a console.

Comment: This kind of thing is impractical without a gui. Why no gui?

Comment: A GUI (graphical user-interface) would make it easier, because Java has the [`JFileChooser`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_jfilechooser.htm) dialog, that allows listing, filtering, choosing and returns the `File` choosen.

Comment: I know, but I have to use specifically a console :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have specified a folder, or use the current working directory.

At least you need two ingredients:

1. a function which lists all **files given in the folder** as option to choose from
2. a user-interface (text-based or graphical) that allows to present those options and let the user choose from them (e.g. by hitting a number of clicking an item from a drop-down-list

#### List files in current directory

Search for [`[java] list files in directory`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D%20list%20files%20in%20directory) and pick:

```java
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
```

#### Text-based UI (TUI) to choose option by number

E.g. from [How can I read input from the console using the Scanner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871520/how-can-i-read-input-from-the-console-using-the-scanner-class-in-java)

```java
// output on console
System.out.println("Choose from following files:");
for (int i=0, i < files.length(), i++) {
  System.out.println(String.format("[%d] %s", i, file.getName()); 
}

// reading the number
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextInt();

// testing if valid, within options index (0..n)
if (i < 0 || i >= files.length()) {
  System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter a number from options.");
}
// file choosen
System.out.println("Your choice: " + file[i].getName());

// other UI operations, like display file, etc.

// IMPORTANT: always close the stream/scanner when finished
scanner.close();
```

Comment: The `listFiles` method allows to pass a `FilenameFilter`, to list only specific files like `.png` images.